# Ruby: Elegant way to pass strings and DateTimes to Time.Parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which takes a DateTime (currently as a string) which i then convert to a DateTime object, for example:

```
def foo(time)
  the_time = Time.parse(time)
  ...
end
```

and so,

```
foo("2012-09-03")
```

I would like to also be able to parse a DateTime object:

```
foo(Time.now)
```

But `Time.parse` complains that I am not giving it a string:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub!' for 2012-08-08 15:59:00 UTC:Time
```

Is there an elegant (one line?) way to return a DateTime object from a string or DateTime object (i would prefer to avoid using if statements)

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the comments - I have no real aversion to using an if statement, I was just seeing if there was anything nicer

Comment: No. You have to test if the `time` variable and find out if it is an integer, and if it is just return the integer.

Comment: You can convert the argument to a string regardless of it's type and it would work, but I think it would not be clear... an if statement would be better I believe...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it without `if` statements:

```
def foo(time)
  the_time = Time.parse(time.to_s)
  # ...
end
```

However if you're looking for an elegant solution, I'd doubt that re-parsing date can be considered as such. Why do you think `if` is a bad option? Here's how I'd do it:

```
def foo(time)
  the_time = time.respond_to?(:to_time) ? time.to_time : Time.parse(time.to_s)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Go with this solution.  It's not just elegant; it's lyrical!  "The time equals time dot respond to to time? [Time dot to time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_After_Time_(Cyndi_Lauper_song))" :-D

Comment: Thanks @PaulFioravanti, I was trying to leverage Duck Typing to its full potential with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using `to_s` on your argument?

```
...
the_time = Time.parse(time.to_s)
...

foo("2012-08-08 15:59:00")
#=> 2012-08-08 15:59:00 +0200
foo(Time.now)
#=> 2012-09-04 16:27:46 +0200
```

Of course in the case of a `Time` object that converts it back and forth, but if you don't want to use an `if`, it's probably the easiest way.